# Composition of Formal Power Series is associative

Tags: generating-functions

How do I go about proving that the composition of formal power series is associative?

I've tried proving the result directly, but the resulting expressions are quite unwieldy. Currently, I'm trying to make use of the topology on $\mathbb{C}[[x]]$, but I can't quite get it to work.

More precisely, I want to prove that if $g(0)=0$ and $h(0)=0$, then $f\circ(g\circ h)=(f\circ g)\circ h$, where $$f\circ g(x) :=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n (g(x))^n.$$

Comment: @Rod: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series

Comment: Do you have any evidenct to suggest that this algebraic property would need a topological justification?

Comment: @rschwieb I don't know about "need," but the idea may be to use associativity for finite polynomials and then take limits, which would use the topology.

Comment: @anon I suppose so :)

Comment: $g(0)\ne0$ and $h(0)\ne0$ prevent the composition from being defined at all. What is $g\circ h$ supposed to be if $g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$ and $h(0)=1$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I edited the question to replace $\neq0$ with $=0$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A formal power series $g(x)$ such that $g(0)=0$ gives you a continuous ring homomorphism $g^*:K[[x]]\to K[[x]]$ uniquely defined by $x\mapsto g(x)$. In fact, $g^*(f)=f\circ g$ (it is clear if $f$ is a polynomial and extends by continuity to power series). As $h^*(g^*(x))=h^*(g(x))=g(h(x))=(g\circ h)^*(x)$, we have $h^*\circ g^*=(g\circ h)^*$. Evaluating both sides on $f$ we get $(f\circ g)\circ h=f\circ (g\circ h)$.

Comment: Right. This is the way to do it, just as the most efficient way to show associativity of matrix multiplication is to use the associativity of the maps that the matrices induce on the vector spaces involved.

Comment: The result is true for arbitrary coefficient rings, so continuity should not be needed.

Comment: @HansEngler:  I do use continuity (neighbourhood's of $0$ are $x^n K[[x]]$); there is no topology on $K$ itself (i.e. it is discrete)

Comment: Also see http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/IAdicTopology.html or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completion_(ring_theory)#Krull_topology for the topology $K[[x]]$ comes equipped with (any topology that $K$ may have is irrelevant to this topology; it is present for arbitrary coefficient rings).

Comment: @user8268 In order to identify polynomials with polynomial functions, you need the field $K$ to be infinite. Is there an easy way to conclude that composition of polynomials is associative over finite fields?

Comment: @AmritanshuPrasad This proof works also for polynomials, not just for power series (just remove the continuity assumption, which now makes no sense, and also the assumption that $g(0)=0$, which is not needed anymore)

Comment: @user8268 I now realize that I had misunderstood your proof. I thought that you were using the associativity of functional composition of polynomial functions to conclude the associativity of composition of formal polynomials. But the main idea behind your proof is already necessary to give a slick proof of associativity of composition of formal polynomials. Lovely.