# Check the associativity of formal series

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, formal-power-series

I am studying for an exam and I am stuck on solving this problem:

Check the associativity for the formal series $F(G(H(z))) = F(G(z))(H(z))$ whenever it is defined.

In one hand, it seems straightforward and intuitive to me, but at the same time I can't find a way how to prove the associativity. But it has to be something simple right?

Comment: Please explain your notation

Comment: For example, if $F(z)$,$G(z)$ are formal power series, then $F(G(z))$ is often not defined.  Perhaps you would want $G(0)=0$.  Then the coefficients of $F(G(z))$ are only finite sums involving the coefficients of $F$ and $G$.  And we can get any given term of $F(G(z))$ using only truncations of $F,G$.  Perhaps this will reduce the question to the case of polynomials.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composition of Formal Power Series is associative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194282/composition-of-formal-power-series-is-associative)